# Masked object disapear when converting image from float32 into uint8

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, mask

Bellow is the following mask showing the detected object by using histogram back projection

[image: float]

**The image has the type float32 which results from the algorithm's output**. I want to detect contours using `cv2.findContours` function.

As you know this function accept a certain image type **which is uint8**, otherwise it raises ans error. Therefore, I converted the image type from float32 into uint8 using `imageFloat.astype(np.uint8)`.

When displaying the new converted binary image (new uint8) it displays a **black image** which means that the detected object is **no longer visible** **(Zero mask)**

[image: black]

So my question is: anyone know why this happens and what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Khaled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not scaling up the values of the image pixels before converting to int, this is the reason why you are facing error.

Do this:

```py
imageFloat *= 255
imageFloat.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks man, this was so trivial and i should have known this. Thanks. Would appreciate for a vote up  :')